# Passport local strategy not getting called when email or password empty

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js, passport-local

I use the following passportjs LocalStrategy:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
  usernameField: 'email',
  passwordField: 'password'
},
  function(username, password, done) {
  // ...
  }
));
```

All works fine if I do provide email and password properties in POST request. But if one of then is empty then this middleware don't get executed but redirect happens.

I need to know what happens and pass req.flash to the client to handle this exception. How could I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [express-validator](https://www.npmjs.org/package/express-validator). It can check your email/password fields in general that they are not empty.

Just require and use it in your app.js entry point:

```
var expressValidator = require('express-validator');
app.use(bodyParser());
app.use(expressValidator()); // then let the app use it, place it HERE after the bodyParser()
```

and in your login/signup route:

```
router.post('/signup', function (req, res) {
     req.assert('email', 'Email is not valid!').isEmail();
     req.assert('password', 'Password is empty!').notEmpty();

      var err = req.validationErrors();

      if (err) {
        req.flash('errors', errors);
        return res.redirect('/login');
      }
// Your passport here....
}
```

And then do your passport stuff like login or signup.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But your approach applies to all requests. Is it possible to apply it to only signin route?

Comment: Yeah, sure! I mentioned in my answer, that you could/ should only use it in your signup route, but I edited my answer with the complete post routing addition. Just use it in your POST- signup route.